# jQuery mobile slider calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm working on an order form based on jQuery mobile, up until now I've been using http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/forms/ for guidance (I'm not very good with JS but I'm learning). So far I have a form with a slider, a select (Yes/No), and a text box for the resulting calculation. All that's left is to take the slider value and multiple it by either a yes value or a no value and display it in the text box. For example, multiply by 8 if set to yes or 10 if set to no.

I've seen some examples of how to do this by converting a DIV into a basic slider but I haven't figured out a way to do it with the jQuery mobile slider. I'm still trying to figure it out but I'd appreciate any ideas.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-docs.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{background:none transparent}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="redirector.php" method="POST" data-ajax="false" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><input type="range" name="slots" id="slots" value="16" min="8" max="18" data-theme="a" data-track-theme="b" /></div>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .containing-element .ui-slider-switch { width: 9em; }
    </style>
    <div class="containing-element" style="">
        <select name="type" id="flip-min" data-role="slider">
            <option value="yes">yes</option>
            <option value="no">no</option>
        </select>
        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <label for="amount" style="margin:6px 6px 0 0">Amount:</label>
            <input style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 2px" name="amount" id="amount" value="" type="text">
        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit_button"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset_button">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6cqC/

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/Y6cqC/1/

Comment: That's a nice start but I was hoping for it to update on slider action as well as toggle.

Comment: now check this one http://jsfiddle.net/Y6cqC/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this one for sliding calculation

```
$("#flip-min").on("change", function () {
   setAmount();

});
$("#slots").on("change", function () {

       setAmount();

 });
function setAmount(){
   if ($("#flip-min").val() == "yes") {
           var a =  $("#slots").val();
          $("#amount").val((a*10));
        }
        if ($("#flip-min").val() == "no") {
           var a =  $("#slots").val();
          $("#amount").val((a*8));
        }
}
```

fiddle [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/jzbeG/1/).

Comment: This works well but actually has one minor flaw, which seems to be common. The math is wrong and "rounds" down. Instead of 50.02 I get 50.0199999 for example. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve that? I've actually looked at several other questions on here and none of their solutions has worked correctly. Here's my latest attempt that works with some numbers and not others, for example 0.78 :
$("#amount").val((a*78/100.0));

Comment: create one fiddle and send we will look.@Bestrafung